# Android - Should I save my object or just its ID via saveinstancestate

Tags: android, android-configchanges

I'm new to Android development and have written a small app that calls a web service and hydrates a relatively simple object (think: auction listing or something of that magnitude). Right now, when the phone rotates and the view is reloaded the web service is re-called, the object is re-hydrated and the listing re-displayed. This seems very wasteful. What is the best practice when storing data via onSaveInstanceState? Is it considered OK to store the object itself, or is it best practice to store the ID and go through the whole process of loading it fresh each time. Are there any other rules of thumb or gotchas to be considered here?

Thank you

JP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even re-creating information form a database is usually considered too much effort for the Android config change scenario.

What you want to use is to create a class holding references to objects which you want to survive the config change, and have your Activity have a reference to that. Also, you will return that in the `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()` callback. In `onCreate()`, you call `getLastNonConfigurationInstance()` to see whether this is a re-creation due to a configuration change. This call will return your object with all the data you need.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are calling a web-service to populate your list, I guess you should store your list's data (calling web-services consumes time and may fail if your user doesn't have a steady connection). Which you can do in different ways (a database, for instance). This approach would also help you if the user restarts your app, since he won't have to wait until the web-service responds.

Also: re-consider your terminology when you ask a question. You don't usually see someone speaking of "hydration" of objects; it's more common to speak of populations and so on.

Comment: It really depends on whether or not all of the data has to be made persistent anyway. If yes, then I agree with you; if not, your suggested approach is not best Android practice. I would assume the auction list which @JP mentions is somewhat temporary.

Comment: @ClassStacker you're right. It depends on the variables involved and on how persistent the data is.

Comment: I've been a developer for 20 years and am not going to change my terminology any time soon. You'll find that hydration is commonly used, especially in the ORM world. Given that both populate and hydrate are arbitrary terms I don't see the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Cache your data as much as you can, every data connection has a "standard" cost in terms of time, resources, and ultimately battery life.

Try to group your requests and make them all in once and cache the responses as long as you can.

[Good read about network on android developers](http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to avoid recalling service when orientation changes then you can add below in your Manifest in activity tag.

android:configChanges="navigation|orientation|keyboardHidden"

But as @DigCamara said, his approach is best and even useful for other scenarios like restarting.